# init variable in c++

Tags: c++

I encountered a strange problem, at times, at no. When I read data from a file to insert into the map, data read from file be attached to a struct type is TradeRecord and then insert to map. But when I init object order_tmp I don't assign value 0 to it so have some field in TradeRecord don't have in the file be assign junk value from c++ compiler.

```
//struct TradeRecord
struct TradeRecord
  {
   int               order;            // order ticket
   int               login;            // owner's login
   char              symbol[12];       // security
   int               digits;           // security precision
   int               cmd;              // trade command
   int               volume;           // volume
   //---
   __time32_t        open_time;        // open time
   int               state;            // reserved
   double            open_price;       // open price
   double            sl,tp;            // stop loss & take profit
   __time32_t        close_time;       // close time
   int               gw_volume;        // gateway order volume
   __time32_t        expiration;       // pending order's expiration time
   char              reason;           // trade reason
   char              conv_reserv[3];   // reserved fields
   double            conv_rates[2];    // convertation rates from profit currency to group deposit currency
                                       // (first element-for open time, second element-for close time)
   double            commission;       // commission
   double            commission_agent; // agent commission
   double            storage;          // order swaps
   double            close_price;      // close price
   double            profit;           // profit
   double            taxes;            // taxes
   int               magic;            // special value used by client experts
   char              comment[32];      // comment
   int               gw_order;         // gateway order ticket
   int               activation;       // used by MT Manager
   short             gw_open_price;    // gateway order price deviation (pips) from order open price
   short             gw_close_price;   // gateway order price deviation (pips) from order close price
   double            margin_rate;      // margin convertation rate (rate of convertation from margin currency to deposit one)
   __time32_t        timestamp;        // timestamp
   int               api_data[4];      // for api usage
   TradeRecord *__ptr32 next;          // internal data
  };

//code read data from file
        while (file.good())
        {
            std::getline(file, line_str);
            boost::split(fields, line_str, boost::is_any_of(k_delimiter));

            // line don't enough data
            if (fields.size() < k_line_fields)
            {
                LOG(DEBUG) << m_log_tag << "Ignore line " << line << ", not enough data: " << line_str;
                line++;
                continue;
            }

            LOG(DEBUG) << m_log_tag << "Data line " << line << ": " << line_str;

            TradeRecord order_tmp;

            order_tmp.login                = atoi(fields[0].c_str());
            order_tmp.order                = atoi(fields[1].c_str());
            strncpy_s(order_tmp.symbol, _countof(order_tmp.symbol), fields[2].c_str(), _TRUNCATE);
            order_tmp.volume               = atoi(fields[3].c_str());
            order_tmp.cmd                  = atoi(fields[4].c_str());
            order_tmp.open_price           = atof(fields[5].c_str());
            order_tmp.margin_rate          = atof(fields[6].c_str());
            order_tmp.open_time            = atoi(fields[7].c_str());

            list_open_order.insert(std::make_pair(order_tmp.order, order_tmp));
            LOG(DEBUG) << std::fixed << "for test, read open order: " << order_tmp.order << ", swap=" << order_tmp.storage;
            line++;
        }
```

Like you can see, in TradeRecord has so many fields but in my file not enough, so c++ auto assign value for these(-92559631349317830000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.000000 something like this)

But I do not understand why this problem is when not because sometimes it is normal

Comment: Off topic: `while (file.good())`, but what about after `std::getline(file, line_str);`? How sure are you `line_str`'s safe to use?

Comment: Search Keywords: "Uninitialized Variable" and "Undefined Behaviour"

Comment: ... so what's the problem?

Answer (score 2):

You should not use a variable without giving it a default value.
In C++ (unlike some other programming languages like Java) do not auto-initialize variables. So in your case, the integer will be in the stack with the value of whatever random data that was there.

Comment: Correction: Only fundamental types are not initialized, for every other type, the default constructor is called. Also, it's undefined behavior, so the value might not be that random.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand your question, but when the compiler gives your variable a random number like 9255698272838000000, it's because you either didn't give this variable an initial value or assigned it to another variable that you didn't give an initial value.

Comment: OK but not always C ++ also assign garbage values ​​to them, when it assigns garbage value, again assigns 0

Comment: it is an indeterminate value, it could be `0`, it also might not be, as you found. There's no guarantee what it will be initialized as

Answer (score 0):

By default, the compiler just allocates memory for the struct's members (or for any variable you create). It does not assign a value to them until you explicitly tell it to do so. For example,

```
int i;
```

allocates an integer but does not give it a value. Because your computer's memory is constantly being passed around (but not zeroed-out) as programs execute and terminate by the operating system, the variable can contain literally any value before you assign it one. It is simply a region of memory, and it will probably contain whatever value it had when it was last used by a (different) program.

The following code:

```
int i = 0;
```

will allocate a variable and assign it a value.

If you initialize your struct like so:

```
traderecord order_temp = {};
```

the compiler will automatically zero-out your structure so all of its members are equal to zero. Then you can simply assign values to each member as it becomes necessary.

Comment: I know that but the bottom line is that these sensory values ​​sometimes appear, not always. I don't know why

Comment: The initial values of all of the variables within your struct will almost always change because they'll almost always be assigned to a different memory region each time you run your program. Try replacing 'traderecord order_temp;' with 'traderecord order_temp = {};' and see what happens.

Comment: Also, you haven't initialized your struct. What happens when you don't initialize your struct, which you can do as I've indicated, is called 'undefined behavior' as mentioned in answers from other users. This is the explanation for why it's sometimes, not always. Undefined behavior means nobody knows exactly what might happen--and nobody knows exactly what your struct might contain unless you initialize it.

Comment: See also: [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAII) which stands for Resource Acquisition Is Initialization. This means that when you acquire a resource (or declare a variable) your should initialize it at the same time.